# Is there any obvious reason this dropdown is failing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an expandable/collapsible menu that when you click on a `<span>` it would show and expand a `<div>`, I followed the tutorial by literally copy and pasting the code, but it doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something really obvious here?

```js
$(".header").click(function() {

  $header = $(this);
  //getting the next element
  $content = $header.next();
  //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
  $content.slideToggle(500, function() {
    //execute this after slideToggle is done
    //change text of header based on visibility of content div
    $header.text(function() {
      //change text based on condition
      return $content.is(":visible") ? "Collapse" : "Expand";
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header"><span>Expected Outcomes of a Corporate Course</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <ul>
      <li>A better relationship with your coworkers.</li>
      <li>A High Trust and open enivornment.</li>
      <li>A safe and fun environment to work in.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you including the jQuery library above the script tag?

Comment: Did you mean to replace the header content with "collapsed" or "expand"? What you have works, just not sure if everything is intended. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JEvYMR

Comment: I am. I wasn't before, so it was throwing an exception at me, but I moved it under the link tag that holds the jquery library and the exception went away, but now it just doesn't work. The inspect tool brings up nothing.

Comment: It seems to work here. The only strange thing is replacing the text of the header with "Expand" and "Collapse".

Comment: @Barmar thats due to the "return" before $content.is(":visible") ? "Collapse" : "Expand";

Comment: @TonyHensler I understand *why* it's happening, I just think it's a strange thing to do.

Comment: The Expand/Collapse messages should probably be displayed somewhere other than replacing the header.

Comment: Yeah it is a strange thing to do, I'm still unsure what they are asking as it works as it should.

Comment: Yeah so I just ran the code snippet on my own post and saw that it was working, but it's still not working on the actual website. That's really weird.

Comment: Are your script tags in the `<head>` or at the end of the `<body>`?

Comment: @JosiahKeller Yes, it's at the top of the document.

Comment: Then you want to use jQuery's `ready` function.